# Create just one SE for all Windows?

Tags: discussion, scope

Now that Windows 10 will run on all devices, it seems that there should be just one SE for Everything Windows, or what do you think?

Should there be one SE or seperate SEs for every device type?

Comment: I think is too soon to make any assumptions about this issue. We don't know exactly what will be the same and what will be specific.

Comment: Also, you could've said that about 8 (with its shared kernel), and it's clear that issues are solved in different ways

Comment: Now that Microsoft has unveiled even more about Windows 10, shouldn't there be some change? Like the name of this SE? Maybe Windows for Phones? Or just Windows? Since the phones will become computers when a screen is attached, I cant really see how you can separate one operating system into several?

Answer (score 7):

I think this not a good idea. While a lot of the client software could potentially run identically across phone / desktop / whatever, there still will be differences in the products and how they are used. Microsoft already demonstrated the adaptive changes a convertible tablet/laptops will have to change to according to its setup and hardware. By extension, the same Windows will change to adapt to a phone interface on a phone, leading to need for a separate SO site.

In either case, until we know more, it is still early for us to have a fully educated discussion on this.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is not a good idea, for two reasons.

First, even though the software will be the same in a very broad sense, there will still be significant differences in how exactly Windows runs on different types of hardware like phones, tablets, PCs, servers and so on. That's too much to effectively combine into a single site without the community getting too unwieldy to manage.

And secondly, this Everything Windows SE would, to a large extent, duplicate existing sites like [Super User](http://superuser.com) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), not to mention this one. Users would need to split their time between two sites, moderators would have a harder time handling duplicates, and so on. Super User, in particular, already overlaps sites like [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) and [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), which has created confusion in the past, and Windows is immensely more popular than either Ubuntu or OS X.

Ultimately, though, if you feel that this is something you want to see happen, you can always start a new proposal at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It was started on Area 51 and people keep complaining. I believe it should be done. One SE site for the whole ecosystem of Microsoft. It will include all questions and there will be tags about windows phone in cases were the questions are specific about windows phone running windows 10 or previous WP OSes

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 already runs on various devices but there are many incompatible parts - Firefox, Chrome, any large applications like Netbeans/Solidworks/etc will not run on Windowsphone, and many people don't look to Windows-store on desktops as the go-to source for Windows desktop apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be done. One whole website for the general Microsoft ecosystem. Windows Phone questions will always be on topic, different tags for different WP OSes and new tags for all the new stuff that will be added. It will be better like this, it will give more life to the current site and more longevity given that W10 merges everything and that more users will come to the newer more global website. Instead covering only windows phone it will cover the whole microsoft ecosystem which ranges from computers to tablets to windows phone and even hardware (wireless display adapter) or online software like office365 and the new Powerpoint replacement called Sway.